# Who is faster: BOOST_FOREACH macros or for

Tags: c++, boost, macros, const-iterator

I tested my program and once decide to change `BOOST_FOREACH` macros to the simple `for` cycle with `const_iterator`.

and i receive unexpected result: program work slower with `for`.

Then i wrote small testing app:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for (int i = 0; i != 50000000; ++i)
    vec.push_back(i);



time_t t1 = clock();
int sum1 = 0;
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    sum1 += *it;
std::cout << ulong(clock() - t1);

time_t t2 = clock();
int sum2 = 0;
BOOST_FOREACH(auto &it, vec) {
    sum2 += it;
}
std::cout << ulong(clock() - t2);
```

here is output:

```
34963
26964
```

Why so?

Comment: You should run it a lot more than one time each and run it in release mode.

Comment: Try it with `-O3` optimisation level (presumably same is meant by comment above). Also you're not caching `vec.end()` in the first loop

Comment: In cases like this, just compare generated assembly listings. 99% says the result will be identical after optimizations

Answer (score 5):

1. You have undefined behaviour in your code. The sum of 0+...+50,000,000 is way beyond MAX_INT. Integer overflow == undefined behavior , undefined behavior== your tests are invalid.
2. Assuming you built the project with full optimizations on, I'm guessing the results happen because of CPU warm-up and due the fact that In the second benchmark, some of the data is already cached. Try switching the benchmarkimg tests and see what happens